# Review audit failed on massively edited post that was now good

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I just failed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4696720) audit. (It currently shows the "this answer was marked as spam or offensive" message; what I was shown in the review was the revision [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23157815/5) along with a suggestion that the length and content were too short, despite the fact that it contained a ton of explanatory text and was clearly not a link-only answer.

When choosing the audit, either the text at the time it was flagged and deleted by a moderator should be shown, or substantially edited posts shouldn't be used at all.

It's still not a good answer to the question, since it's a python solution to a PHP question, but it's certainly not Low Quality.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this - two other people failed that audit and didn't. I've undeleted the answer now to prevent it from catching anyone else. Excluding edited posts is probably sane here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting with the next build, posts that were edited after they were deleted will not be eligible to become an audit in the Low Quality queue.

Comment: Is this also the case with the Close Queue ? I got bitten several times by the "review audit failed" on already closed question that I found were in a good enough shape (and had been edited by the OP after comments).