# Review audit failed on edited and improved question

Tags: feature-request, review-audits

I just failed this audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5165103, and I think this audit should not have shown up.

Feature request: I believe that if a closed question is edited, it cannot be used as for a review audit. At least, you can't use the edited question!

Analysis: This seems a variation on [this feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253051/53974), which was slightly different (applied to posts, not to questions) and already accepted.

---

Maybe I still should have voted to close the question, but that's irrelevant to the feature request. So please restrict answers to the main point.

(If you want to correct me, feel free to discuss this side point in comments, or point me to a relevant discussion.

My rationale: The question was tagged as "unclear what you're asking", but was later edited clarifying precisely the point. It's still a beginner's question, but I see a genuine struggle to learn, so closing does not seem necessarily appropriate.)

Comment: The key difference between this request and the linked VLQ one is that edited CVQ posts have already been reviewed by 5 people in the reopen queue and not 1 person thought the edit salvaged the post.

Comment: OK, if the software checked that, then the feature is implemented and the question is just about whether genuine beginner questions are welcome, which is a different one. I'll mark your comment as accepted answer, if you explain what CVQ means.